# Python post request returns 500

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am using requests to make a POST request to create a user. The request succeeds with 201 created when I use curl, however fails with a 500 response when I use requests. My curl command is

```
curl --user administrator:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://localhost:8080/midpoint/ws/rest/users -d @user.json -v
```

And my python script is:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

with open('user.json') as j:
    data = json.load(j)

response = requests.post('https://localhost:8080/midpoint/ws/rest/users', headers=headers, data=str(data), auth=('Administrator', 'password'))
print(response)
```

Can anyone see a reason why my python script would be failing? I am at a loss.

Comment: in your curl statement, you have `administrator` but in your requests call, you have `Administrator`

Comment: Sorry, I keep interchanging them which is confusing to read. It's not actually case sensitive and the curl command works with both and I have tried they python with both to the same end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str(data)` returns the Python representation of `data`, not its JSON representation.  These two forms can differ in things like `'` vs. `"`, `True` vs. `true`, and `None` vs. `null`.  To properly JSONify `data`, call `json.dumps()` on it:

```
response = requests.post(..., data=json.dumps(data))
```

or let `requests` do the JSONification:

```
response = requests.post(..., json=data)
```

or use the JSON as it appears in `user.json` directly:

```
with open('user.json') as j:
    data = j.read()

response = requests.post(..., data=data)
```

Comment: This worked! I can't thank you enough, I've been reworking this for ages trying to find the problem and finally understand what's wrong. Thank you again for your help!